# Safely appending to a list in a Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, collections, thread-safety, task-parallel-library, plinq

I have the following code

```
var myResponse = new Response();
Parallel
.ForEach(itemsListDto
         , new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }
         , itemDto => {
                         var tResponse = _itemService
                                         .InsertItem
                                            (itemDto
                                             , new RequestMessage 
                                                   {UserName = RequestUserName});
                          myResponse.AddErrors(tResponse.Errors);
                       }
         );
return myResponse;
```

It seems that `myResponse` isn't getting all the `Errors` added to it.  How should I rewrite this to be safe?

Comment: Please post the definition of `AddErrors`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to synchronize access to `myResponse`, since it sounds like the `AddErrors` method is not thread safe:

```
var myResponse = new Response();
var syncObj = new object();
Parallel.ForEach(itemsListDto, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, itemDto =>
    {
        var tResponse = _itemService.InsertItem(itemDto, new RequestMessage {UserName = RequestUserName});
        lock(syncObj)
            myResponse.AddErrors(tResponse.Errors);
    });
return myResponse;
```

If `InsertItem` is a fairly lengthy process, this may be acceptable in terms of performance.

If `InsertItem` is a fairly fast method, this may add a lot of synchronization overhead, and cause the overall time to approach a synchronous loop.  In that case, you could potentially use the overloads of [Parallel.ForEach which provide local state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486.aspx) to lock less frequently, and store the errors in your local state, then aggregate at the end of the full loop.  I have an article describing the [process required to aggregate data efficiently using `Parallel.ForEach`](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/22/parallelism-in-net-part-4-imperative-data-parallelism-aggregation/) in detail.